Which is most common or best practice for import syntax?
I have used both of these syntax styles for importing Solidity contracts:
import "./contract.sol";
or
import { ContractName } from "./contract.sol";
I would like to know which one is more standard or considered best practice in the Solidity community. Is there a specific scenario where one should be preferred over the other?

The named import i.e.,:
import { ContractName } from "./contract.sol";

is considered as the best practice, because it allows you to only import the required contract(s) from the file, that comes handy in case when multiple contracts, interfaces, libraries, etc. are defined in the same file.
Suppose the file contract.sol contains three contracts, like:
contract A {
   // Body of contract A
}

contract B {
   // Body of contract B
}

contract C {
   // Body of contract C
}

Then, you can import either one, two or all the three contracts in another file, depending on your requirements, like:

Importing only contract A:
import { A } from "./contract.sol";


Importing only contract B:
import { B } from "./contract.sol";


Importing only contract C:
import { C } from "./contract.sol";


Importing contract A and B:
import { A, B } from "./contract.sol";


Importing contract B and C:
import { B, C } from "./contract.sol";


Importing contract A and C:
import { A, C } from "./contract.sol";


Importing contract A, B and C:
import { A, B, C } from "./contract.sol";



Thus, by using named imports, you can target specific functionalities required in the importing contract. This approach allows you to import only the necessary contract(s), avoiding unnecessary functions from non-targeted contracts in the same file. As a result, the generated bytecode is optimized.
PS. You can also use named imports to import libraries, interfaces, structs, custom errors, and other global declarations that are outside any particular scope.
For more explanation, you can refer to this answer.

Thank you for your detailed explanation! It makes a lot of sense and clarifies the advantages of using named imports.

You're welcome. Happy coding!
